# Line integral using substitution

Tags: integration, area

Using Green formula calculate the area that is bounded with curve:$(x^2+y^2)^2=2a^2(x^2+y^2)$. My main problem is how to find $x,y$ in polar coordinates. When i worked with double integrals i would use $x=r\cos\phi, y=r\sin\phi$ but here in solution it is used $x=a\sqrt{2}\cos t\sqrt{\cos 2t}$ and $y=a\sqrt{2}\sin t\sqrt{\cos 2t}$. So I'm not sure how to think in this situation and on what it depends choose od $x,y$.

Comment: You seem to have a typo in the equation of the curve? Is it $x^2 - y^2$ on RHS?

Comment: No, in book it is +, is it mistake?

Comment: Yes it should be minus based on the parametrization.

Comment: Yes, you must be right, otherwise it would be canceled. Still do you mind explaining how to know what substitution to use?

Comment: OK I just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, $x = r \cos t, y = r \sin t$

So we have,

$(x^2+y^2)^2 = 2a^2(x^2-y^2)$

Or, $(r^2 \cos^2 t + r^2 \sin^2t)^2 = 2a^2(r^2 \cos^2 t - r^2 \sin^2t)$

$r^4 = 2a^2 r^2 (\cos^2 t - \sin^2t)$

$r = \sqrt2 \, a \, \sqrt{\cos 2t}$

Now plug this back in $x, y$ and you have,

$x = \sqrt2 \, a \, \sqrt{\cos 2t} \cos t, y = \sqrt2 \, a \, \sqrt{\cos 2t} \sin t$

Comment: Everthing clear, thank you a lot!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: If you are finding area of this curve, please be careful with the limits of $t$. Draw it and see - it is a curve with $2$ petals.

Comment: Is it from $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: Yes that is correct. There is another petal to the left of $y$-axis. So just multiply the area by $2$.

Comment: Got it, thanks again.